# Case statement in WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table 'Route' with Id ,Name and Active columns. If Id = 0 I want to select all the Id's where Active = true.

If Id > 0 I want to select the data for particular Id where Active = true.

I tried with following Query. But not working. (here I passed 2 for a Id value.) 
Can someone support me?

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 2

SELECT  DISTINCT Id ,Name 
FROM    Route 
WHERE
CASE WHEN @ID > 0 
THEN Id = @ID AND Active= 1
ELSE
Active=1
END
```

Sample Data Attached.

[image]

Comment: I tried that. But failed

Comment: Is `Active` a string field (`'True'`) or an integer field (`1`) ?

Comment: Active is a Boolian Field

Comment: For clarity you should consider using only `True` in both cases or only `1` in both cases, so that it is clearer what you're doing, and not mix, it looks confusing.

Comment: To Fred: If this is duplicate can u tel me answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use case can be done using where clause only.

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 2

SELECT  DISTINCT Id ,Name 
FROM    Route 
WHERE Active=1 AND (Id = @Id OR @Id = 0);
```

**Explanation:**

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN @ID > 0 
THEN Id = @ID AND Active= 1
ELSE
Active=1
```

a. if @ID > 0 then Id = @ID AND Active= 1

b. else Active=1

If you look into both cases closely, Active= 1 remains same in both cases so it can be taken safely to outside of the condition

Then the remaining part is, if @ID > 0 then Id = @ID i.e. select the row as per the parameter value when parameter has valid value, otherwise select all.

So, if you combine both it becomes

```
WHERE Active=1 AND (Id = @Id OR @Id = 0);
```

Comment: Yes, check if it gives you desired output. Otherwise you can provide sample data and expected outcome. So that we can verify

Comment: Here even If I pass 3 for Id still all data showing.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Not working. I have attached sample data to my question. Can u look at.

Comment: Is Id is a parameter? as it's a column name of the same table.

Comment: Satyajit : Can u try now with sample data and query which I have edited in my question

Comment: Yes. For Id I'm passing the value from program. Data should listed according to passed ID. If Id = 0 all data should listed

Comment: Satyajith : this is working..But I can't understand whats happening here in this query. can u explain?

Comment: Added explanation in the answer, check if it helps